# join 3 tables odd error message

Tags: sql, join

I have the following sql statement that is joining 3 tables..

```
SELECT A.category, A.ssn, A.categoryText, B.summary, B.form, C.regNr, C.account
FROM tableA A 
JOIN tableB B ON A.category = B.category
JOIN tableC C ON A.ssn = C.ssn
WHERE B.form = 0
```

I'm getting the error

```
Invalid column name 'ssn' (line 1)
```

But when I join `tableA` and `tableB` only like this:

```
SELECT A.category, A.ssn, A.categoryText, B.summary, B.form--, C.regNr, C.account
FROM tableA A 
JOIN tableB B ON A.category = B.category
--JOIN tableC C ON A.ssn = C.ssn
WHERE B.form = 0
```

then I get no error at all!

What am I doing wrong?

tia

Comment: please post your real queries. (I suppose you don't call your columns col1, col2 ....)

Comment: No I don't, but I don't see the importance of this? is it because they are more readable?

Comment: Are you sure that the table `tableC ` has a column `ssn`? btw, what database are you using?

Comment: then may be `C.ssn` not exist?

Comment: tableC doesn't have ssn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your schema for table C does actually include the ssn column & it's spelled correctly (i.e. you don't have a typo causing the issue).

Depending on DB platform the other things to look at are whether the collation in use on your DB is causing a failure due to a mis-match on case sensitivity.  E.g. is the column called 'SSN' in table c rather than 'ssn'?

Comment: thanks a lot for opening my eyes to this! never thought that case sensitivity is an issue in sql server!

Comment: It's only an issue if your database is set to use a case sensitive collation - this has caught me before when I've worked on a customer server set for case sensitivity which I don't normally use.